# Creating a JS function that will save the console.log to a .txt file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I currently have a small website which uses the HTML input tag outputs the values to console (with console.log).

I need a function to store the list of values as a text file from the console. For example when I click the submit button at the bottom of the form, it should automatically start the download.

Is there any way? Is this possible with javascript or any other language?

Console looks like this:

Name: John Doe
Age: 25
Gender: Male
......... etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could override console.log so that it records what is being output to the console along with writing it.  You could then download what was recorded.  To override console.log see http://udidu.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/override-console-functions.html